# How to find the array from the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

```
const str = "[1,2,3,4],5,6";

const getArray = (str) => {
...
return arr;
}

console.log(getArray(str));  //[1,2,3,4]
```

`[1,2,3,4]` is the expected array.

How can I get this one?

Comment: What have you tried so far? where did you get stuck?

Comment: Also, is the array always supposed to contains only digits or your input string could be, for example `"lorem[1, a, true, { key: value }], ipsum, dolor, sit"` or something similar?

Comment: Please share what you have tried. It helps while answering.

Comment: `JSON.parse(str.match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` for extracting the numbers enclosed by `[]` then run a `map` for sanitize. Check this-

```js
const str = "[1,2,3,4],5,6";

const getArray = str => {
    const regex = /(\[([^\]]+)\])/;
    const match = regex.exec(str);
    
    return match?.[2] ? match[2].split(',').map(x => x.trim()) : [];
}

console.log(getArray(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array of all arrays within your string.

```js
const str = "[1,2,3,4],5,6";

const getArray = (str) => {
  const ans = []
  let stack = []
  let isStack = true
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '[') {
      isStack = true;
    } else if (str[i] == ']') {
      isStack = false;
      ans.push(stack)
      stack = []
    } else if (isStack && str[i] != ',') {
      stack.push(parseInt(str[i]))
    }
  }
  return ans;
}

console.log(getArray(str)) // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
console.log(getArray(str)[0]) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript method [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find the **`[`** and **`]`**.

This will give you all characters in-between **`[`** and **`]`**.

Then you can use the [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to convert the array.

Using **[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)** you can convert string to number

```js
const str = "[1,2,3,4],5,6";

function getArray(str){
  var myArray = str.substring(
    str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1, 
    str.lastIndexOf("]")
  );
  return myArray.split(",").map(Number);

}

console.log(getArray(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that str contains exactly one pair of enclosing square brackets:

```
const getArray = (str) => {
  const idxStart = str.indexOf('[') + 1
  const idxEnd = str.indexOf(']')
  arr = str.slice(idxStart, idxEnd)
  return arr.split(',')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegEx` to match the string enclosed in `[]`

```js
const str = "[1,2,3,4],5,6";

const getArray = (str) => {
  arr = str.match('/\[.*\]/')[0]
  return arr;
}

console.log(getArray(str));
```